# How to make a array of html content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Here is the HTML:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>one</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>two</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now I need to make an array of second column of that table like this:

```
var arr = ['one', 'two'];
```

How can I do that?

I can select the table like this `$('table')` and get its content like this: `$('table td+td')`, but I don't know how can I make an array of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:nth-child()` to select second `td` and `map()` to return array [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1287/)

```
var arr = $('table td:nth-child(2)').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

Comment: Should you not mark it as duplicate instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Use `$("table td:nth-child(2)").each()` to loop through all 2nd td and get its text using `.text()`

```
var arr = new Array();
$("table td:nth-child(2)").each(function(i){
  arr[i] = $(this).text();
})
```